# Loop through SQL results and insert them into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, t-sql

I'm writing a stored procedure. I'll explain my problem with some sample code below.

```
-- Create a temp table 
CREATE TABLE #FoundRequests 
(
    RequestID INT
);

SELECT RequestID 
FROM Requests 
-- Don't worry about the WHERE clause for now
```

Which returns a result set:

```
| ID   | RequestID |
+------+-----------+
| 1    | 824       |
| 2    | 922       |
| 3    | 954       |
```

How would I get reach `RequestID` from this result set and insert each found value into my temp `#FoundRequests` table?

I tried different things like `STUFF()` and `SPLIT(@ID_VALUE , '')` but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why do you think you need to "loop" or use STUFF/SPLIT? This should be a simple `insert into #FoundRequests (requestID) select requestID from Requests;`

Comment: Im new to this  .... and that worked thank you for the help ... I cant believe it was that simple

Comment: I find that hard to believe.

Comment: This doens't look like MySQL. T-SQL is used with SQL-Server, not MySQL.

Comment: I would recommend some basic training if you are going to be doing more SQL. Start [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-t-sql-dml) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert all records from `Requests` table into `#FoundRequests` with the following query:

```
insert into #FoundRequests(
     RequestID INT
)
select RequestID from Requests;
```

If needed you can also add where clause into your select to filter results.